# Hotkey to go to the function the cursor is on - Delphi

Tags: delphi, ide, hotkeys

To go to a function/procedure I use Control + Click and Delphi will take me there (on a good day).

Is there a fast way to do that without using the mouse?

Comment: I don't think there is one, but I'd love to be proven wrong on this. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Code_Editor#Code_Browsing_.28Ctrl-Click.29

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that functionality does indeed have keyboard access: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>.

These keyboard shortcuts are documented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts

Comment: Thanks, I had looked through a different list of shortcuts and didn't see it. The one you posted looks more comprehensive.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to David's answer, a pretty complete list of Delphi's Editor Key and Key Combinations can be found here: [DelphiEditorKeyTable.pdf](http://www.jensendatasystems.com/DelphiEditorKeyTable.pdf) (compiled from Cary Jensen and Brian Long)